# How can i use es6 modules in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import express into my project using ES6 syntax, but it keeps giving me the error:

```
import express from "express";
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I have done a bit of research and found where people were saying to add:

"type":"module"

to my package.json file, which I have done:

```
...
"description": "Shopping list to learn the MERN stack",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
...
```

But I'm still getting the same issue.  I would prefer to use the import ES6 syntax rather than this syntax.

```
const express = require('express')
```

Comment: What tutorial did you follow to enabled es6 with node?

Comment: Are you using babel?

Comment: I've actually gone through several articles trying to figure this one out, but the latest (that I can find) says to use "type":"module" for node 12 in order to enable ES6.

Comment: are you running node with the `--experimental-modules` flag?

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: I'm using v12.4.0.  I tried the --experiemtal-modules flag, but that didn't seem to work either.  I'm still having issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Solution:

For me the best, easiest and most compatible way to resolve (dated to *September 2019*) was to:

- `npm install esm`
- ensure that the script is run by `node` with the `-r esm` option.

Simple as that.

---

## The Node way:

*(according to the [ECMAScript Modules  Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules))*

Other than the `"type": "module"` property into `package.json` NodeJS requires the scripts to be run via `node --experimental-modules <your_script.js>`.

Code into either `.mjs` or `.js` extension files will be treated with the support for new ES6. Renaming that I find pretty inconvenient.

**Note:** `"type": "module"` is particularly important for supporting `.js` files. Read the linked documentation.

The solution provided by NodeJS with the `--experimental-modules` flag **didn't work for me in all cases**. ‍♂️

Adding the `esm` packages is more maintainable; and reliable. And can be easily/quickly removed once the ESM support won't be experimental anymore.

---

## Offtopic tip:

If you want to **run tests on your ES6** `import/export` code, I suggest to rely on a solid/flexible framework, like Mocha.

You can follow [this instructions to run Mocha tests supporting ES6](https://alxgbsn.co.uk/2019/02/22/testing-native-es-modules-mocha-esm/).

Trying with *Jest* I wasn't able to run test successfully. Apparently they don't want to directly support the experimental ES6 and suggest to transpile the code (thing that I hate).

---

#### *References:*

- https://alxgbsn.co.uk/2019/02/22/testing-native-es-modules-mocha-esm/
- https://timonweb.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-ecmascript-6-imports-in-nodejs/
- https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules

Answer (score 5):

If you try to run **Node js** app with **ES6 syntax**, you will encounter this kind of error

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

**let's fix that**

*install three main packages*

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/node
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

add `.babelrc` file with this

`{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] }`

and this in `package.json`

```
"start": "nodemon --exec babel-node app.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, after doing even more research on the ES6 way, this is what worked for me.  It's a combination of an answer above and the following:

**package.json**

```
node --experimental-modules server.mjs
```

**server.mjs**

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const db = process.env.MONGO_URI
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a nodejs boilerplate supporting es6 module.

https://github.com/jasonjin220/es6-express-rest-api-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

You need Babel transpiler to do this, as Node.js doesn't support es6.

First add these packages to your project :

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015 rimraf
```

Then, create a `.babelrc` file , this is used by Babel transpiler to know some information during transpilation. 
`touch .babelrc`
Then, add this line to .babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

This tells your Babel to use es6 presets as per 2015 standard.

Then, modify the package.json and tell it to use transpiler.

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"build": "rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist/ --ignore ./node_modules,./.babelrc,./package.json,./npm-debug.log --copy-files",
"start": "npm run build && node dist/index.js"
 },
```

You have to add the following to script section, this line tells when you run `npm run start` , the transpiler will first convert the es6 syntax to minmal JavaScript one, later that is used.

Check your dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.15.2",
"morgan": "^1.8.1",
"rimraf": "^2.6.1"
 }
```

And Dev dependencies :

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.24.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0"
}
```

This should work, comment if there is any issue.

Comment: node 12, which OP says they are using, does support the esm import syntax and does not require babel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Babel,

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

then for usage create a .babelrc file if you don't have it, with options:

```
{"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]}
```

then ad devDependencies in package.json

`"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",`

that should do the job.